# Permission denied (publickey) when trying to clone EC2 repository from local PC

Tags: git, amazon-web-services

I am trying to clone a git repository that I have setup on my ubuntu EC2 instance.

`git clone ssh://ubuntu@test.myurl.com/var/git/testcase.git`
This is run on my local windows computer.

It results in the error `Permission denied (publickey). Could not read from remote repository.`

I am unable ot understand why this is not working. I already used `ssh-add C:\Users\Username\Docouments\MyKey.PEM` This PEM file shouldn't be the problem because I can SSH into the server via Putty with that same PEM file.

*EDIT*

Result of running `ssh -v ubuntu@test.myurl.com`

`OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to test.myurl.com [51.**.***.166] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 8d:3c:a9:08:a3:42:63:13:f8:b9:b7:bc:6e:4b:c6:44
debug1: Host 'test.myurl.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: "*This PEM file connects successfully to the server*" With what server user? `ubuntu`? Can we see the results of `ssh-add -l` and `ssh -v ubuntu@test.myurl.com`?

Comment: @phd I updated that quote to make it more clear. Ubuntu is the server. The result of `ssh-add -1` is 1 result which is my PEM file. The result `ssh -v ubuntu@test.myurl.com` has been added to the question as an edit.

Comment: `ssh-add -l` <- that's lowercase letter L, not digit 1.

Comment: @phd Oh. My bad. The result of running that is `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent`.

Comment: Seems ssh client cannot find private key. Perhaps it'd be better to convert PEM to DER and specify the key in config file as the key for the host.

Comment: I'l go ahead and convert that. Although, I'm not sure how I would setup the config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host test.myurl.com
    IdentityFile C:\Users\Username\Docouments\MyKey.PEM
    User ubuntu
```